# Listing all combinations produced by picking one element from each of several sets

Tags: list-manipulation, combinatorics, sets

I have a problem like this, I am given the following sets `{a,b,c}, {d,e,f}, {h,i,j}`. I want to pick one element from each set, and output a list of all the possibilities. The output will be a set of sets, all which have the length `3`. I have tried many different approaches now.

Comment: `Tuples[{{a, b, c}, {d, e, f}, {g, h, i}}]`, check the documentation of `Tuples` for more information.

Comment: Hey thanks that works well, I never thought about using tuples

Comment: To those voting to close again I'd like to ask: what are you searching for that makes this easy to find?  I'm not saying it's not easy to find, but I'd like to see that proven.  There are *many* functions in *Mathematica* and the mere existence of a documentation page is not proof enough to close a question as "easily found in the documentation" IMHO.

Comment: @Pinguin I am in favor of you posting that as an answer.

Comment: Also seems like a good question to keep for the googlability of the title. It's #1 hit for "mathematica all combinations one from each" and `Tuples` documentation isn't even on the first page.