# Generate all strings of fixed length from an alphabet

Tags: list-manipulation, permutation

I am trying to create all possible strings of length $8$ from the alphabet $\{+1,-1\}$. I am trying to get help from this [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5036/finding-all-length-n-words-on-an-alphabet-that-have-a-specified-number-of-each-l). But not sure where to start from.

Any help?

Comment: Would this be what you're after, `Tuples[{-1, 1}, 8]`?

Comment: Similar questions: [4486](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4486) (dup. [32212](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/32212)), [15885](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/15885) (dup. [20794](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/20794)).